# axis labels overlap each other in polar chart

Tags: highcharts

is it possible to config that the labels will not overlap in polar chart?

http://jsfiddle.net/Zt66h/

$(function () {

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        polar: true
    },


    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 10,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return "this is long text that overlap";
            }
        }
    },          

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 0,
            pointInterval: 10
        }           
    },

    series: [{
        data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        pointPlacement: 'between'
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately the highcharts doens't contain detection-collision mechanism, so you can increase widht/height or set useHTML as true, return class on the labels (by formatter) and then use CSS styles to overwrite posision.